# How can I properly handle nested scrolling in VerticalViewPager with a LazyColumn inside?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-launcher, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I'm trying to simulate a launcher app. It has a main main screen and an apps drawer. I've implemented this with a VerticalViewPager: page 0 is the main page and page 1 is the app drawer. That way, I can swipe between both pages (as most launchers can do). The problem is that I want to display the installed apps on a list in the page 1 (drawer), and to do so I'm using a LazyColumn/LazyVerticalGrid. When going from page 0 to 1, everything goes OK. The problem comes when trying to swipe from page 1 to 0 (app drawer). It can't handle it properly and mixes LazyColumn overscroll with VerticalViewPager transition, ending in the UI getting stacked in the middle of the transition from page 0 to page 1.

I've tried using gestures listeners (such as `Modifier.pointerInput(Unit)` or `NestedScrollConnection`) but the logic becomes a mess soon and I couldn't make it work. I'm specting to work as follows: once you open the drawer, then you can scroll up and down on the LazyColumn to see the apps; but when the scroll position of the LazyColumn is 0 (not scrolled) and the user swipes down, it should close the drawer and show the homescreen, following the finger (normal behavior of a VerticalViewPager). This is basically how most launchers work. Maybe I need to use a different approach, but this is the only one I could think of. Any help would be welcomed!

EDIT: I've been going through this a little bit in depth and using a `NavHost` with a transition between homescreen and drawer might be useful. The transition state should follow the finger somehow. Anyone else thinks this might be useful?

Comment: Maybe a [BottomSheet](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/bottom-sheets) would be more suitable in your case.

Comment: I've tried using a BottomSheet but I don't know how to control the opening of the Sheet; I mean, how can I make it follow the finger while opening.

Comment: That's a good question. If you consider a `BottomSheetScaffold`, you can define a `sheetPeekHeight` on which you can drag the BottomSheet upwards. However, then the "peekSheet" is always visible, and I don't know if this is what you want your UI to look like.
Maybe [https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/pointer-input/understand-gestures](Jetpack Compose Gestures) can help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried that approach but with no luck. I also tried to define a scrollable modifier in LazyColumn to track the 'delta'. Basically when user scrolls down and firstItemVisibleIndex is 0, the I can call animateScrollToPage() in the VerticalViewPager. But delta value keeps changing for a few seconds after the scroll of LazyColumn has finished (?). No good results with this approach neither.